# Debugging live stack frames in Common Lisp ( SBCL) .How does the debugger/compiler implement this capability?

Tags: lisp, sbcl

Lisp allows one to recompile segments of code during debugging producing live stack frames. I know that lisp is dynamic and that it's easy to rebind a symbol associated to a method. However Lisp also easily allows to redefine single forms inside a function. This is even more powerful and flexible than what C# and Java debuggers can do. Why and how does it work?  Why modern languages do not provide the same level of sophisitication? Where I can find some papers or books so to learn more?

Comment: Kent Pitman wrote about the condition system [here](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/Papers/Condition-Handling-2001.html). And there is an interesting discussion on [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1544).

Comment: Stackoverflow is best for actual programming problems. General questions and getting recommendations of outside resources like books,etc. is best asked somewhere else... the Stackoverflow help says: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

It's not magic. I did the same in the old days in assembly. I created a DOS TSR program that pointed the interrupts I could handle to my own location. When you did a division by zero or something like that it jumped into my program and the stack had all the previous programs stack and where it had gone wrong. I just provided a menu with ways to mend it so that it didn't exit with DOS default behaviour.

In CL you have like a default exception handler that calls a function that you can see your options on restarts. Restarts are like code within the scope of where the error originates with ways to mend the situation. It's possible to make something like this in any language that has exceptions and closures. The debugger and restarts become a part of the running program and thus it becomes more safe on the cost of less performance. [Here is a JavaScript implementation](https://github.com/zkat/cond).

There is a way to turn it off and it might make your programs faster in CL. The standard does not require to do anything so it's optional, but implementations do make unsafe fast code that might end up as a segmentation fault instead of the debugger.

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that because the stack is not unwinded like in other tradional managed languages like c# there is stil a way to patch the erroneous function and resume execution from the right location in the newly compiled function , right?

Comment: to be able to recompile, replace functions or to reinvoke stack frames has no connection to the condition system...